# C++ shared_ptr how to ensure thread safety?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, shared

all:
 According to [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) c++ implementations typically uses atomic ref count to ensure thread safety, but this seems buggy in some cases.

```

```
void func2(shared_ptr<int>* x) {
  shared_ptr<int> a(*x);
  *a += 1;
}

thread func1() {
 shared_ptr<int> a1(new int(10));
 thread t (func2, &a1);
 return t;
}
```

```

As the above code shows, if the copy construction in func2 happens after the internal reference count of a1 decreases, the pointer will get deleted twice, right?

Comment: The buggy thing here is *your* code ... dangling raw pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An atomic reference count assures that only the reference counting is thread safe. It doesn't turn the referenced class into a thread safe class. It doesn't prevent you from writing thread-unsafe code, like passing a pointer to a `std::shared_ptr` to a new thread, but destroying it before the new thread has an opportunity to acquire its own copy of it.

You are still responsible for writing thread-safe logic. But you can rely on reference counting being thread-safe.